# Implementing a scheduler for a backup program

Tags: c#, automation, backup

for a backup program I am doing I have already finished the GUI. Now I want to do the functional requirements. Each backup can have schedules. There are predefined settings like every Sunday or Monday but the user can also specify his own schedules.

As I have never done anything like this, I was wondering what a good approach would be to running a backup every x hours or days. I was thinking about using Threads or writing a service but both fields are totally new to me. What would be the best method here?

Comment: Backup program is Web Application or Winform?

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

If threaded development and service development are both totally new then I think you will struggle to implement this in a useful way.  Even so...

Scheduler-type applications are best run as services, because otherwise you need the user to be logged in to be running the application.  Services run independently of the user being logged in.

Because of this, however, services don't have a user interface so your GUI needs to package up the details of schedule into a configuration file somewhere, then signal the service to re-load that configuration file so that the service will then know what to do and when to do it.

The service will normally spawn a worker thread to do pretty much everything, and that worker thread needs to be able to respond to the service being shut down (read up on `AutoResetEvent` to see how this might be done across threads).  The thread will then wait until either an event or for the appropriate time to arrive and then do whatever it has to do.

None of this is actually complicated, but I suggest you do some digging into multithreaded programming first.

Comment: ok so I have somewhat understood your post, what is unclear is how will the service know what to do? In my program, lets say I have a function that writes the current time to a file. But if I am not logged in and didn't execute the program, how will the service know how the function looks and works? or can I execute the program from the service without any user being logged in?

Comment: You can execute the program from the service without anyone being logged in.  If the program that it executes has a user interface then it will run into problems, but if it just does something silently then this will work OK.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ColinM, Services are best for the Scheduler Type of application.
You have to combine the Services with application to run your code at scheduled intervals.
See the article for more details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163821.aspx